# What is the right way to handle errors?

Tags: python

My script below scrapes a website and returns the data from a table. It's not finished but it works.  The problem is that it has no error checking.  Where should I have error handling in my script?

There are no unittests, should I write some and schedule my unittests to be run periodicaly. Or should the error handling be done in my script?

Any advice on the proper way to do this would be great.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
''' Gets the Canadian Monthly Residential Bill Calculations table
    from URL and saves the results to a sqllite database.
'''
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


class Bills():
    ''' Canadian Monthly Residential Bill Calculations '''

    URL = "http://www.hydro.mb.ca/regulatory_affairs/energy_rates/electricity/utility_rate_comp.shtml"

    def __init__(self):
        ''' Initialization '''

        self.url = self.URL
        self.data = []
        self.get_monthly_residential_bills(self.url)

    def get_monthly_residential_bills(self, url):
        ''' Gets the Monthly Residential Bill Calculations table from URL '''

        doc = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
        res_table = soup.table.th.findParents()[1]
        results = res_table.findNextSibling()
        header = self.get_column_names(res_table)
        self.get_data(results)
        self.save(header, self.data)

    def get_data(self, results):
        ''' Extracts data from search result. '''

        rows = results.childGenerator()
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            if row == "\n":
                continue
            for td in row.contents:
                if td == "\n":
                    continue
                data.append(td.text)
            self.data.append(tuple(data))
            data = []

    def get_column_names(self, table):
        ''' Gets table title, subtitle and column names '''

        results = table.findAll('tr')
        title = results[0].text
        subtitle = results[1].text
        cols = results[2].childGenerator()
        column_names = []
        for col in cols:
            if col == "\n":
                continue
            column_names.append(col.text)

        return title, subtitle, column_names

    def save(self, header, data):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Bills()
    for td in a.data:
        print td
```

Comment: To make your script more "bullet-proof" you should at least surround I/O operations like urllib2.urlopen with try/except blocks.

Comment: I (conditionally) disagree. As others have said, you catch errors you can actually do something about. If it's correct behavior for his program to continue if it can't access that URL, than catch the error and continue on. However, there are often many more cases when you want to stop as soon as something goes wrong. What if his app updated a database with the results of the fetch? In that case, it may be more appropriate to let `urlopen` fail and stop execution.

Comment: Unit tests are not "error handling". You might have a unit test to verify that a function returns an appropriate value when given valid input, and that it throws the appropriate exception when given invalid input, but your function needs first to be written to handle errors before you can do this. Unit tests are intended to verify that code is correct - correct code still often needs to handle errors, e.g. to cope with bad input.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation of all the functions and see what all `exceptions` do they throw.

For ex, in `urllib2.urlopen()`, it's written that [Raises URLError on errors](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen). It's a subclass of `IOError`.

So, for the `urlopen()`, you could do something like:

```
try:
    doc = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except IOError:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Error opening URL'
```

Similary, do the same for others.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense to me to catch errors on urllib2.urlopen() as if I can't connect, the rest of the script should not work. Because this is a scraper, how can I handle any error that may come if the webmaster changes their page?

Comment: @user1190201 You would have to check what the methods like `findAll()` and others return. If they return an `empty list` or `None`, you can know that something wrong happened. In your code, you can get `index out of range` exceptions too if the website changes it's page so that can tell you too that something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You should write unit tests *and* you should use exception handling. But only catch the exceptions you can handle; you do no one any favors by catching everything and throwing any useful information out.

Unit tests aren't run periodically though; they're run before and after the code changes (although it is feasible for one change's "after" to become another change's "before" if they're close enough).

Answer (score 0):

A copple places you need to have them.is in importing things like tkinter
try:
   import Tkinter as tk
except:
   import tkinter as tk
also anywhere where the user enters something with a n intended type. A good way to figure this out is to run it abd try really hard to make it crash. Eg typing in wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "where should I have error handling in my script?" is basically "any place where something could go wrong", which depends entirely on the logic of your program.

In general, any place where your program relies on an assumption that a particular operation worked as you intended, and there's a possibility that it may not have, you should add code to check whether or not it actually did work, and take appropriate remedial action if it didn't. In some cases, the underlying code might generate an exception on failure and you may be happy to just let the program terminate with an uncaught exception without adding any error-handling code of your own, but (1) this would be, or ought to be, rare if anyone other than you is ever going to use that program; and (2) I'd say this would fall into the "works as intended" category anyway.